# Realizar DI en startup de mi web api core.net 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Tengo un proyecto n-layered con DotNET 3.1 y donde mi capa de **application** donde están ya agrupados mis viewmodel y dto, en mi capa de servicios webapi tengo en mi startup donde registro mis dependencias:

```
  public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddScoped<IProductsAppService, ProductAppService-- poner la Implementation-->();
        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

donde coloco la implementacion

> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: page.Application.Interfaces.IProductsAppService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType

, no entiendo porque tengo que referenciar mi controller (ProductsController)
Y en mi controller donde tengo ...

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly IProductsAppService ProductFactory;

    public ProductsController(IProductsAppService productFactory)
    {
        this.ProductFactory = productFactory;
    }
```

ya he revisado esta [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) pero no logro entender bien.

Tengo que usar un Trasient scope o singleton? estoy en fase de aprendizaje
**Update**
mi clase que debe implementar en el service es:

```
    public class ProductAppService : BaseAppService<Products>, IProductsAppService
{
    private readonly IProductsService ProductsService;

    public ProductAppService(IProductsService productsService) : base(productsService)
    {
        this.ProductsService = productsService;
    }
 }
```

Comment: tienes 3 interfaces inyectadas en tu controller pero solo 1 defines a tu IServiceCollection

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea Si voy a modificar el codigo pero aun asi me sale error en el que pretendo implementar